# Is engineering still a good career for Americans?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Obviously it is a good career for indians. But it seems like ME is becoming EE and the adoption of various technologies has deskilled the job to the point where 90% of the available positions are outsourced or taken by h1bs. Is engineering still a good career with viable employment?

Comment: Absolutely yes, no doubts here.

Comment: Aren't you, like, a current or former h1b?

Comment: Define “good” career. Define “viable” employment...

Comment: At least able to get a job

Comment: Unfortunately, virtually no degree courses in any subject teach students "how to get a job", and a significant proportion of the graduates never figure it out for themselves.

Comment: I immigrated to US in 82 with years of experience in my homeland in concrete and steel framing. Took me a year or two to get used to 2x4 and plywood. But I got my first job fairly soon by just word of mouth and after 4 years opened my own engineering practice. Around me, southern California, there was a lot of demand for structural engineers. I retired three years ago, bought an airplane and am flying for fun. To me design and supervision of the job-site was very exciting, the machinery, cranes, trades-people all of it. But after a bout of cancer I decided to hang it and open my wings .

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like an [academic guidance question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/261/1832). Such questions often involve personal choice and can probably be better answered by an adviser or counselor. We do not believe this site's format is well-suited to such questions, which are therefore considered off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is most Americans are too lazy or more interested in having fun ( A K A liberal arts courses). Other than medicine; engineering is the most reliable area to get a good paying job . Now if you want to be a multi-millionaire , you need to invent some new kind of computer chip or develop a new social website. But if you want a good job with good money and , and at least I felt I was doing something worthwhile, engineering is great. I saw Americans become unwilling to put in the work starting in about 1970. Then it was the UK "brain drain" ; of course I did not realize it at the time. Our R & D department hired over a dozen PHDs from UK in a couple years. I am certain the American managers would have been happy to hire qualified Americans if they could find them. I often went to lunch with a Brit I worked with , so at lunch it was me and a half dozen guys who talked funny - ( what car has a bonnet ?). And today; My stepson just got a PHD in the the medical field ( not a medical doctor) and newsletter from his prestigious hospital containing promotion and advancement news had about 20 photos . Of the 20 about 3 looked like "Americans" ; again ,I expect the administrators would hire any qualified Americans they could find them . And, a little overkill, A grandson that my son and I encouraged to go into engineering , got way more "friends" on Facebook than semester hours of credit . After four years of fun and about 4 changes of majors , he needs about 2 years to graduate and I lost track of his current major , but I am sure he is having fun.

Comment: And the schools are "dumbing down" to match their students. My degree was Metallurgical Engineering. But , today my school and most others do not offer it , I guess it is too hard. If you want to learn a little metallurgy they offer a course of Mechanical and Aerospace Engineering ( there may even be a third field in the title.). Like we barely learned metallurgy in 4 years , and now they add two more or less unrelated subjects in the same time. I bet is is more fun than just old metallurgy.

Comment: also, providing good resources to teach just about any engineering course is expensive - most other degrees are cheap in comparison. Cost of installing & maintaining a wind tunnel. Axial flow pumps etc

Comment: @blacksmith37, the "dumbing down" is world wide. Engineering is not like  liberal arts courses where in you just have to think you know what you are talking about. And we have the school, Uni -> teacher, professor arrangement where the tutors have only ever lived in academia. Unfortunately we no longer have tutors for the more advanced studies.